# Does Google Compute Engine support sub-domains and if so, is there a limit?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm considering building an SaaS application to be hosted on GCE (Google Compute Engine) where each user would get their own sub-domain when they sign up. For example

```
user_1.mydomain.com
user_2.mydomain.com
user_3.mydomain.com
```

Users will also be able to link a custom domain to their sub-domain i.e. instead of using user_1.mydomain.com, they could use mycustomdomain.com.

Is this possible in GCE? If so, is there a limit to the maximum number of sub-domains that can be supported? Any tips, information or links to documentation will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: GCE provides virtual machine infrastructure. I would assume you wants to deploy application on GCE platform, now depending upon the webserver you use, it will require server to configure per your requirement. For example: [Wildcard subdomain](https://steinsoft.net/static/archive/2014/steinsoft.net/index5d37.html?site=Programming/Articles/apachewildcarddomain) configuring [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) and use [URL redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). I am not aware of any limit that GCE impose on sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

The first part should be possible. Add a domain with a wildcard in Google Cloud Engine and use the following documentation to route the requests: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url

The second part is more complex. Every domain requires verification. The user should change DNS and add a record.

If you want add/verify programatically domains. You could do it commandline or create a process for it. See the following documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains

Hope you can do something with my answer

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by adding a domain with wildcard in GCE and/or a link to documentation on this? 
The 2 links you provided are for app engine. Is the process the same on GCE?

Comment: Some documentation can be find at https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart to create records. First you need configure the DNS to receive calls. You can create a wildcard DNS record for *.mydomain.com. The ip address need to be an instance ip address. 

Example record: *.mydomain.com A 3600 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

in the instance you need some configuration to listen to the individual subdomains